# PHP Check whether Socket is still connected

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying out sockets in PHP. I only have experience with such things in C#, Java and Basic. In C# and Java there's a function called "Connected" or "isConnected", but in PHP I can't find such a function to check whether the socket is still connected or not. 
I read that I've to send or receive data to check, but is there a way to check the connectionstate of a socket without sending or receiving, cause the check has to be in an if-clause where a new socket will be created in array or an old one will be used. The sending and receiving of data is in another function.

Some code which works, but always uses a new entry in array...

```
$Worker = Array();

        while($this->Listener)
        {
            $accept = socket_accept($this->Listener);
            if($accept)
            {
                $jumpout = false;
                for($i = 0; $i < count($Worker); $i++)
                {
                    if(!$Worker[$i]) // check whether socket is connected or not
                    {
                        $Worker[$i] = $accept;
                        unset($accept);
                        $this->Logger->Write("New Client connected - " . $i);
                        $jumpout = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!$jumpout)
                {
                    $Worker[count($Worker)] = $accept;
                    unset($accept);
                    $this->Logger->Write("New Client connected - " . (count($Worker) + 1));
                }
            }
            socket_listen($this->Listener);
        }
```

Doesn't give the socket any event or option without using complicated threading stuff or some other complicated things ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-status.php

Comment: I believe sockets always remain connected unless explicitly closed at your end or at remote end.  if at remote end there's no way of telling if its open or closed until you try reading/writing to what you think was an open socket. socket_get_status() is unreliable

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php

Comment: Why is it unreliable @Dave?

Comment: its a wrapper stream_get_meta_data() neither of which can be used with the socket() function! and it doesn't always return what you'd expect it to return especially if using non-blocking sockets.  There's plenty of info including some "work arounds" on both links provided by yourself and volkinc

Comment: So.. If i understood, there's no way to check ? Or there's a way, but unsafe ?

Comment: There's an unreliable way that basically doesn't work (depends how you've opened your socket of course) then there's work arounds probably better to setup/create a heatbeat structure assuming your sockets are for receiving and you're writing a client to connect to them just build in a 1 second single packet heart beat if the server doesn't received a heartbeat for a created socket (tracked via an array of existing sockets) then it can safely assume to close the socket after say 3 failures or something

Comment: I think you should consider two levels of "socket is connected". If you want to check if a socket is connected because no peer has closed it before the check.. well, this can be done with the appropriate function. If you want to check if a socket is connected meaning that the next packet sent will be received.. well, you can't know what will happen until you try to do it. NOTE that this is true for all languages.

Answer (score -2):

Try socket_get_status with an if else. It should return the status of the socket.

To read more about how to use it see an example at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-status.php

Comment: As Dave said in the comments above, socket_get_status only work with stream sockets, it doesnt work with socket_create or socket_accept ones. Check this: https://gist.github.com/mcuadros/9604673